# events doesn't work in appended view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

events doesn't work in appended view in backbone

here is the method of the view:

```
events: {
  'click .toolbar_ship': 'openProfile'
},
openProfile: function() {
  gameView.$el.append(profileView.render().$el);
}
```

here is profile:

```
events: {
  'click .object_in_inventory': 'inventoryClick',
  'click .object_in_cell': 'cellClick',
  'click .close_profile': 'closeProfile'
},
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template());
  return this;
},
closeProfile: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
}
```

at first profile is appended correctly and all binds on click works nice, but when I close profile and then one is opened none of clicks work.

I even can't understand why it happes, I will appreciate your help.

here is an example of click:

```
$('.wrapGate').bind('click', function() {
.....
}
```

Thank you)

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from an implementation of `openProfile` method.

You are using there instance of `profileView` which you have initialized somewhere like

```
var profileView = new ProfileView();
```

`ProfileView` extends from `Backbone.View` and when you are initializing it will [delegate events](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-138)
and will bind them to `this.$el`.

When you are calling jQuery's `remove()` method on `this.$el`, it will remove it and will unbind all attached events.

Next time when you will call `openProfile`, `profileView.render().$el` will return your view but without any events.

---

To avoid this you need to refactor your code. There is a few cases how you can implement this task. One of them is to always use new instance of `ProfileView` like:

```
events: {
  'click .toolbar_ship': 'openProfile'
},
openProfile: function() {
  var profileView = new ProfileView();
  gameView.$el.append(profileView.render().$el);
}
```

and in ProfileView:

```
events: {
  'click .object_in_inventory': 'inventoryClick',
  'click .object_in_cell': 'cellClick',
  'click .close_profile': 'closeProfile'
},
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template());
  return this;
},
closeProfile: function() {
  this.remove(); // this.remove() is the method of Backbone.View, which will manage removing of view and unbinding of events.
}
```

---

Another solution can be just hiding the profile view when user clicks on close profile

```
events: {
  'click .toolbar_ship': 'openProfile'
},
openProfile: function() {
  if (this.profileView) {
      this.profileView.$el.show(); // your custom showing logic
  } else {
      this.profileView = new ProfileView(); // caching profileView
      gameView.$el.append(profileView.render().$el);
  }

}
```

and in ProfileView:

```
events: {
  'click .object_in_inventory': 'inventoryClick',
  'click .object_in_cell': 'cellClick',
  'click .close_profile': 'closeProfile'
},
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template());
  return this;
},
closeProfile: function() {
  this.$el.hide(); // your custom showing logic
}
```

Don't forget to manage ProfileView removing and events unbinding when you will not need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to your "el" property, the view that u r appending should be inside your el

```
eg: el : "#container" // must set

    <div id="container">
      .
      .
      .
      .
   <div id="new-appended-views"></div>
     .
     .
    </div>
```

the events will work for all newly appended views